# Возможно ли изменить стили для другого элемента при условии?

Tags: css

К примеру у меня есть элемент с классом `.my-class1`, а также динамичным классом `.my-class1-2`(элемент тот же, класс то появляется, то исчезает при каком-то условии(у меня это открытие и скрытие меню при нажатии на бургер)). 
Также есть отдельный элемент с классом `.my-class2`
Знаю что отсутствие класса можно задать через псевдокласс `:not`
Возник вопрос, возможно ли изменить стили для элемента с классом `.my-class2` только если элемент с классом `.my-class1` не содержит класса `.my-class1-2`, тоесть `.my-class1:not(.my-class1-2)`

Comment: Зависит от того как расположены `html` блоки. Добавьте пример вашей верстки.

Comment: Конкретный пример вмконсоль добавь и будет тебе решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы можете задать такое условие только если `.my-class2` находится ВНУТРИ `.my-class1:not(.my-class1-2)` либо ПОСЛЕ него (сам или в контейнере). В общем, один из вариантов:

```
.my-class1:not(.my-class1-2)  .my-class2
.my-class1:not(.my-class1-2)  + .my-class2
.my-class1:not(.my-class1-2)  ~ .my-class2
.my-class1:not(.my-class1-2)  + %element% .my-class2
.my-class1:not(.my-class1-2)  ~ %element .my-class2
```